# Replacing Ckeditor with ActionText in a Rails 6 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I replaced CKEditor with ActionText in my rails 6 application, the upgrade to rails 6 and installation of action text was smooth.

I want to ask how I can be able to migrate the data from my model attribute to the newly established action text association (well not exactly migrate, I want to be able to display the old data and even be able to edit/update it).

For example, I have a `description` attribute in my model that was used with CKEditor before, now I have changed that field to a `rich_text` field like this: `has_rich_text :description`

So now all references to `description` simply query its `rich_text` association.

If I wanted to do something like this in my view, how can I achieve that?

```
@model.description (display if rich_text data is present) || @model.description (or try this if rich_text data is blank, also display nothing if both is blank)
```

I'd like to achieve this for show, edit, update and delete actions. Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just migrate the Ckeditor columns to the the new `action_text` table?

```
class ConvertCkeditorToActionText < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    action_text_rich_text_statement = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.prepare('action_text_rich_text_statement', <<-SQL)
      INSERT INTO action_text_rich_texts (
        name, body, record_type, record_id, created_at, updated_at
      ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
    SQL

    Rails.application.eager_load!

    transaction do
      Post.all.each do |post|
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.exec_prepared(
                'action_text_rich_text_statement', [
                  'body',
                  post.body,
                  "Post",
                  post.id,
                  post.created_at,
                  post.updated_at
                ])
      end
    end
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Comment: What would be the steps involved in migrating the @posts.body, for example, to the new table? How would the migrated data stay linked to the correct user? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TomConnolly added a migration example